# Qt4 qwidget after shown event

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I need to handle an event that is fired after widget is fully visible like after show event. But I cannot find any event like that in Qt4. I already tried the solutions suggested below. But none of them worked.

My aim: I am working on an embedded system and I am using Qt for UI. What I am trying to do is to show hardware accelerated camera on UI after CustomWidget is shown. If I use showEvent, camera is shown before CustomWidget is fully drawn.
It seems that showEvent is fired before widget is fully drawn. It behaves like before show event.

## Failure-1

```
bool CustomWidget::event(QEvent *event)
{
   bool returnValue = QWidget::event(event);
   if (event->type() == QEvent::Polish)
   {
       this->camera->show();
   }
   return returnValue;
}
```

Polish event is called once. When I hide and show the widget again and again, it never fired.

## Failure-2

```
void CustomWidget::showEvent(QShowEvent *event)
{
    QWidget::showEvent(event);
    QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(dialogExec));
}

void CustomWidget::dialogExec()
{
    this->camera->show();
}
```

This did not work either.

## Failure-3

```
void CustomWidget::paintEvent( QPaintEvent *event )
{
   QWidget::paintEvent( event );

   if( !this->camera->isVisible() )
   {
       this->camera->show();
   }
}

void CustomWidget::hideEvent( QHideEvent *event )
{
   this->camera->hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`QWidget` has protected members called `closeEvent( QCloseEvent* event )` and `showEvent( QShowEvent* event )`. Maybe you can use these methods to manage the camera.

Comment: showevent does not work. Read the second paragraph of the question please. if it is not clear, please inform me and I will clarify my statement.

Comment: does `camera` inherit `QWidget`? is `camera` able to refresh to itself? if both answers are true, maybe you can simply increase the offset of `QTime::singleShot` method.

Comment: Camera doesn't inherit QWidget. It is a gstreamer-based class. If I increase the offset of QTime::singleShot, it definitely solves my problem. But it is not a good solution. There are lots of widgets in my application and switching among these widgets takes different time. So I have to find the most time-consuming switch operation and make this value the offset of the singleShot method. This is definitely not a nice solution.

Comment: Ok. If you need to show the camera when the dialog is fully painted you need to overload `QDialog::paintEvent` method. Maybe you can emit a signal when `paintEvent` finished and connect this signal with a method that shows the camera. `void CustomDialog::paintEvent( QPaintEvent* event ){ QDialog::paintEvent( event ); emit dialogPainted( ); }`

Comment: I already did that. See #Failure-3. Instead of emitting a signal, I  called show method of camera instance. I don't think that just changing code to emit a signal solves my problem.

Comment: #Failure-3 overloards `CustomWidget::paintEvent`, I propose overload the event in the dialog containing `CustomWidget`.